# Opening jQuery UI Dialog box with dynamic content and then dynamically react to click in the dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to populate a jQuery dialog with dynamic content from a getData.php file. That works fine so far via:

```
$("#buttonGetData").click(function() {

  $.get("getData.php", function(data){
      $("#dialog").html(data);
      $("#dialog").dialog();
      return false;
  });
});
```

The getData.php just gives something back like:

```
<p id="data1" class="data">data1</p>
<p id="data2" class="data">data2</p>
<p id="data3" class="data">data3</p>
```

My problem now is: How do I add a dynamic click listener to each data row so I can use the clicked data in my site? I want each 'p' be clickable and then use the data inside for setting its content to a 'textarea'.

The problem seems to be, that the new dynamically added rows arent part of the JS from the site, so I can't reach them via a clickListener.

How would this be done correctly? Thank You!

Comment: You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I am looking into this right now. It looks promising. I will report back if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you get html related data result using Ajax like you used $(get)... , your newly generated html from Ajax cannot be used for jQuery code OR in other word jQuery/JS don't recognized your newly added html elements generated from Ajax. There is a way you can achieve your required result. You can send your jQuery/JS code with html codes to Ajax from your file (getData.php) as String.In your getData.php you can echo like this.

```
echo '<p id="data1" class="data">data1</p>';
echo '<script>';
echo "$(document).on('click', '#data1', function(){alert('DATA1 Clicked');});"
echo '</script>';
die();
```

Above may be very straight forward answer so there is another way which may be more convicting. You can also used delegation on based on event handler. Examples:

```
$("#dialog").on("click","p", function(){
  alert("DATA1 Clicked");
 // your code to add content of this element to textarea
});

$("#dialog").on("click","#data1", function(){
  alert("DATA1 Clicked");
 // your code to add content of this element to textarea
});

$(document).on('click', '#data1', function(){
    alert("DATA1 Clicked");
 // your code to add content of this element to textarea
});
```

One of them should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I was assuming something like this. But, how would this help? The javascript in the php file, which I would add via echo, wouldn't have access to the JS in my main html file, no? Doing an standalone like you did there like "alert" works, but I want the clicked data to be parses to my main html file, from which the AJAX call was initiated. For example: click button, ajax call, data fill into the dialog. Then user clicks on row x, and then the page will fill a textarea of the main html page with the data x content.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please do check them if that will solve your problem.